# Which Java HotSpot JIT compiler is running?

Tags: java, jit, jvm-hotspot

I would like to know if my no VM argument invocation of HotSpot Java is running with -client, -server, or tiered compilation options. When I supply no VM arguments, which one is chosen by default? Is there a way to output diagnostics about which JIT compiler is running?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming this is Hotspot:

```
-XshowSettings:vm
```

For example, on my Windows box I get output of:

```
VM settings:
    Max. Heap Size (Estimated): 1.77G
    Ergonomics Machine Class: client
    Using VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
```

Comment: Thanks Jon. I am running Hotspot on OS X, but for Java 1.6 & 1.7 that option is unrecognized, alas.

Comment: @JulienChastang: That's odd - it's fine for me on both Windows and Linux. What does `java -X` show?

Comment: My bad. Actually on 1.6 it is unrecognized, but on 1.7 it gives me the sort of information you provide above. Curiously, when I supply the java -client -XshowSettings:vm it still claims to be Server. Charles Nutter (http://blog.headius.com/2009/01/my-favorite-hotspot-jvm-flags.html) seems to suggest that if you are on 64 bit, -server is the only option. It would be nice to get some clarity about this from Oracle.

Answer (score 2):

From the program that is run, you could query the `java.vm.name` property to differentiate between client and server mode. On hotspot it will contain "Server" if you have used that option (for example: `Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM`).

According to [this page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/vm/performance-enhancements-7.html):

> Tiered compilation is now the default mode for the server VM.

Note: it works now but is probably not the most future-proof approach.

Answer (score 1):

Slightly better method of determining which JIT compiler is in use.

On a Windows machine with 32-bit JDK8:

```
    $ java -version
    java version "1.8.0"
    Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0-b132)
    Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.0-b70, mixed mode)

    $ java -XshowSettings -version 2>&1 | grep sun.management.compiler
        sun.management.compiler = HotSpot Client Compiler

    $ java -server -XshowSettings -version 2>&1 | grep sun.management.compiler
        sun.management.compiler = HotSpot Tiered Compilers
```

So the Client Compiler is the default with the Windows 32-bit JDK8
and the '-server' option gets you the 32-bit Tiered Compiler.

On a Windows machine with 64-bit JDK8:

```
    $ java -version
    java version "1.8.0"
    Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0-b132)
    Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.0-b70, mixed mode)

    $ java -XshowSettings -version 2>&1 | grep sun.management.compiler
        sun.management.compiler = HotSpot 64-Bit Tiered Compilers
```

So the Tiered Compiler is the default with the Windows 64-bit JDK8.
Oracle does not provide a 64-bit Client VM.